# Как работает git merge --squash?

Tags: git, git-merge

Заметил что иногда вместо `git pull --rebase` делаю так

```
git checkout remote_my/branch_my
git merge --squash branch_my
git commit ...
```

В чем смысл такого кода

Comment: В git'е вообще многие вещи можно сделать разными способами с одинаковым или похожим результатом.

Comment: мне просто некоторые говорил что якобы это дает моментально подлить изменения, а pull --rebase долгая операция если ты сделал много комитов и кто то засинкался с основной веткой где тоже много комитов

Comment: pull - это fetch+merge. т.е. дольше чем merge на время выполнения fetch. Даже если в удаленном репозитории нет изменений мы имеем, как минимум сетевую задержку. Просто merge работает локально.

Comment: pull --rebase это fetch+rebase, именно rebase это дорогая операция если много было изменно в remote. И вроде как проще переключиться на удаленную ветку и закинуть один комит в конец мержем тоесть ff (fast forward)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Из [Git Reference - merge](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-merge):

> **--squash**
>
> Обрабатывает рабочую область и индекс таким образом, как будто было произведено слияние (merge), но при этом не делает фактического коммита, не перемещает указатель `HEAD` и не записывает ничего в  `$GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD`. Это позволяет сделать единый коммит к текущей ветке, содержащий все те же изменения, которые были бы применены при обычном слиянии с веткой (или несколькими, в случае сложного слияния).

#### Как это работает

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash feature123
git commit -m'merged feature #123'
```

Все изменения в ветке feature123 становятся одним коммитом в ветке master.

Это удобно, если ветка содержит много незначительных коммитов, которые «неинтересны» для общей истории. После такой операции история ветки останется «плоской», так же как после `git pull --rebase`.