# Как смержить ветку, не передавая историю коммитов?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-branch

Например, у меня есть ветка мастер с начальным коммитом. На ветке `dev` закончена работа по версии `1.0` проекта репозитория, и всего коммитов было сделано 35 штук. Как залить на мастер `HEAD` `dev` ветки, а остальное опустить?

Иными словами, как можно передать `HEAD` ветки на другую, но при этом не передавать всю историю коммитов?

P.S. Меня не интересует удаление папки `.git` со всеми возможными конфигами и алиасами, не интересует меня и создание `release`'ов. Меня интересует именно слитие `HEAD`'а одной ветки в другую.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то можно глянуть ответ в ссылке выше. Хотя, возможно, имеется в виду банальный `squash`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9683279/4827341

Comment: @АлексейШиманский почитал про `squash`. Скорее всего то, что надо, но непонятно как пользоваться.

Comment: @KitScribe пробовал посмотреть на ruSO в поиске? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/434008/191482 ,...https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/462268/191482 ....... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bgit%5d%20squash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

предположим, что у вас есть ветка `master` с одним начальным коммитом:

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline master
73cc54877ad5bffc5d908a3b4984d2b3e99dc9a5 initial commit
```

и есть ветка `dev` с тремя уникальными коммитами (с заголовками`a`, `b` и `c`):

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline dev
0fd210d83659398fe6a4b1289e373011624df2df c
d95279eecc06398163feed519cdcaaca2dfec255 b
99917d9c75baf4e6dfa57a5ca4feb5d7c54769a8 a
73cc54877ad5bffc5d908a3b4984d2b3e99dc9a5 initial commit
```

и вы хотите, чтобы в ветке `master` была такая примерно история:

```
какой-то хэш ........................... a+b+c
73cc54877ad5bffc5d908a3b4984d2b3e99dc9a5 initial commit
```

где коммит, озаглавленный `a+b+c`, представлял бы собой все изменения, произведённые коммитами `a`, `b` и `c`.

---

#### вариант 1, более длинный и «гибкий»

1. переключитесь на ветку `master` (хотя для тренировки лучше использовать «кошек», т.е., создать новую ветку из ветки `master`: `$ git checkout -b test master`):

   ```
   $ git checkout master
   ```
2. «заберите» в неё все коммиты из ветки `dev`:

   ```
   $ git merge dev
   ```

   сейчас история будет выглядеть так же, как и у ветки `dev`:

   ```
   $ git log --pretty=oneline
   0fd210d83659398fe6a4b1289e373011624df2df c
   d95279eecc06398163feed519cdcaaca2dfec255 b
   99917d9c75baf4e6dfa57a5ca4feb5d7c54769a8 a
   73cc54877ad5bffc5d908a3b4984d2b3e99dc9a5 initial commit
   ```
3. выполните команду

   ```
   $ git rebase --interactive 73cc548
   ```

   где `73cc548` — это хэш того коммита, который должен «остаться как есть» (в примере — тот, который был самым последним в ветке `master` до начала манипуляций).

   1. откроется редактор с таким примерно содержимым:

      ```
      pick 99917d9 a
      pick d95279e b
      pick 0fd210d c
      ```
   2. первую строку, про коммит `a`, оставьте «как есть», а у всех остальных строк замените `pick` на `squash` (можно сократить и до одной буквы — `s`):

      ```
      pick 99917d9 a
      s d95279e b
      s 0fd210d c
      ```
   3. сохраните изменения и завершите редактирование.
   4. откроется редактор уже с другим содержимым — коммит-сообщениями:

      ```
      # This is a combination of 3 commits.
      # The first commit's message is:
      a

      # This is the 2nd commit message:

      b

      # This is the 3rd commit message:

      c
      ```
   5. сотрите все эти строки и оставьте «единое описание» коммита. например, что-нибудь вроде:

      ```
      a+b+c
      ```

      или

      ```
      merge dev branch
      ```

      или что вам там требуется.
   6. сохраните изменения и завершите редактирование.
4. всё. вы получили в текущей ветке историю всего из двух коммитов:

   ```
   $ git log --pretty=oneline
   42604cdaea79f11018dcc58a607790f3f4573d80 a+b+c
   73cc54877ad5bffc5d908a3b4984d2b3e99dc9a5 initial commit
   ```

   причём последний коммит (озаглавленный `a+b+c`) содержит все изменения, которые были (и есть до сих пор) в ветке `dev`.

#### вариант 2, более короткий

можно воспользоваться командой `merge` с опцией `--squash`.

1. переключитесь на ветку `master` (хотя для тренировки лучше использовать «кошек», т.е., создать новую ветку из ветки `master`: `$ git checkout -b test master`):

   ```
   $ git checkout master
   ```
2. выполните команду:

   ```
   $ git merge --squash dev
   ```

   при этом коммитов создано не будет, но в индексе будут сохранены все изменения, которые были произведены в ветке `dev` (убедиться можно командой `$ git status`).
3. просто закоммитьте эти изменения:

   ```
   $ git commit -m 'a+b+c'
   ```
4. всё. вы получили в текущей ветке историю всего из двух коммитов:

   ```
   $ git log --pretty=oneline
   62c5f52a4918b94026c494c40ce535af9967acde a+b+c
   73cc54877ad5bffc5d908a3b4984d2b3e99dc9a5 initial commit
   ```

   причём последний коммит (озаглавленный `a+b+c`) содержит все изменения, которые были (и есть до сих пор) в ветке `dev`.

Comment: У вас в обоих случаях fast-forward merge. Принципиально за этот путь агитируете или так случайно вышло? :)

Comment: Кстати, можно `--pretty=oneline` заменить на просто `--oneline`.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, такова ситуация у автора вопроса (насколько я её понял).

Comment: Отлично, спасибо!